# How to split a small part of string?

Tags: python-2.7

I have a text file with different information which in part of it there is date (hour, min, and sec) separated by ":". I am going to extract only the date information from each line.

For example:
date =
1902-07-09  3:38:00   27.08     56.34
1902-07-09  3:38:00   27.08     56.34
1902-07-09  3:38:00   27.08     56.34
.
.
.

```
for j in range(len(date)):
     date_time = re.split(':', date[j][12:20])
```

I expect the output being as below by using split:

```
date_time[0] = 3
date_time[1]=38
date_time[2]=00
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just `str.split()`:

```
date_str = '1902-07-09 3:38:00 27.08 56.34 1902-07-09 3:38:00 27.08 56.34 1902-07-09 3:38:00 27.08 56.34 ...'

date_time = date_str.split()[1].split(':')
print(date_time)
```

Prints:

```
['3', '38', '00']
```